# Regex for extract specific interface

Tags: regex

I want create a Regex that get specific interface in a list.

I have this interface list:

```
interface0/0/8.120
interface0/0/8.130
interface0/0/8.1035
interface0/0/1.1035
interface0/0/0.120
interface0/0/0.130
interface0/0/8
interface0/0/1
interface0/0/2
interface0/0/4
```

I write this expression for get interface that not end with 120,130,150

```
.+?(?=\.(?!120|130|150))
```

with this regex I get:

```
interface0/0/8.1035
interface0/0/1.1035
```

if I want get the previus list and the same interface without subinterface (.1035)

```
interface0/0/8.1035
interface0/0/1.1035
interface0/0/8
interface0/0/1
```

I test this in https://regex101.com/

Regards,

Dario

Comment: What tool are you using? `.+?(?=\.(?!120|130|150))` returns `interface0/0/8` and `interface0/0/1`

Comment: Try `(.+?)\.(?!(?:120|130|150)\b)\d+` and get Group 0 (the whole match) and Group 1 (the part before `.`). See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G5WzrZ/1)

Comment: the 2nd part of the task requires some programmatic interruption, I guess

Comment: Try `^(?![^.]*\.1[235]0).+`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/O1vL1G/1

Comment: I use Regex in Zabbix, is right that return interface0/0/8 and interface0/0/1 but in disceovery I have interface with subinterce.

I cannot get group 1 or other group, I need get interface0/0/8.1035 interface0/0/1.1035 interface0/0/8 interface0/0/1 this interface only with regex

this regex ^(?![^.]*\.1[235]0).+ not work for me because get interface0/0/2 interface0/0/4 that I don't want.

Comment: Try this: ^.*?(?!\.120$|\.130$|\.150$)(?=\.\d+$)

Comment: How do you know how to exclude `interface0/0/2` and `interface0/0/4`? Should the final match be `interface0/0/8 interface0/0/1 interface0/0/8 interface0/0/1`?